# Are there way to replace User-Agent in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, user-agent, ionic6

The plugin that was originally used seemed to be disabled in ionic 6.
If anyone knows how to do it, please let me know.
https://ionicframework.jp/docs/native/user-agent/